# Which format is preferrable to publish book dataset (plain or preprocessed)?

Tags: dataset, language-model

When I decide to publish collection of book texts as a dataset, should I do some preprocessing first or should I publish "plain texts"?

For example, https://huggingface.co/datasets/bookcorpus is published as a collection of sentences (so basic preprocessing was done), but https://huggingface.co/datasets/bookcorpusopen is published with raw texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the content and the potential applications but it would not make a huge difference.

Plain text has a slight advantage in making studies at the book level and lets people preprocess it to the sentence level if needed. The other way round is possible but you might lose some information like paragraphs or titles that could be useful in some cases.

Comment: meanwhile I found one more reason: legal issues when publishing full text, and less legal problems when publishing random sentence split.